# How to get values provided by Groovy DSL from Kotlin in Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose following configuration:

`build.dependencies.gradle`:

```
ext {
  libraries = [:]
}

libraries += [
  library : [group: 'com.example', name: 'library', version: '1.1.1']
]
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
apply(from = "build.dependencies.gradle")

dependencies {
  implementation(libraries["library"]) // does not work
}
```

Is there a way to get values provided by Groovy script in `build.gradle.kts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t work because Kotlin is statically/strongly typed language unlike Groovy. `libraries` is not defined on any object from Gradle’s API.

You can access it like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation((project.extra["libraries"] as LinkedHashMap<*, *>)["library"]!!)
}

println(project.extra["libraries"])
```

`project.extra[“libraries”]` returns an `Object` so we need to cast it correctly in order to get the next value. It is also marked as `@Nullable` so hence the `!!` operator.

—

A better way to manage dependency versions is to leverage [Java Platform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) plugin.

Comment: How can you access one the keys from library like the group or name